# Addition within lambda calculus

Tags: logic, arithmetic, lambda-calculus

I've been reading "The Emperor's New Mind" by Roger Penrose. He briefly introduces lambda calculus (pp. 86-92) and gives this formula for addition:

$A = \lambda fgxy.[((fx)(gx))y]$

This was my attempt at using it:

$$
A = \lambda fgxy.[((fx)(gx))y] \\
1 = \lambda an.an \\
2 = \lambda bm.b(bm) \\
A12 = \lambda xy.( ( ((\lambda an.an)x) ((\lambda bm.b(bm))x) )  y) \\
= \lambda xy.[ ( ((\lambda an.an)x) (\lambda m.x(xm)) )  y] \\
= \lambda xy.[ ( (\lambda n.xn) (\lambda m.x(xm)) )  y] \\
= \lambda xy.[ ( x((\lambda m.x(xm)))  )  y] \\
= \lambda xy.[   ( x(\lambda m.x(xm))   ) y] \\
$$

Is it legal to transform the last step into $= \lambda xy.[x(x(x(y)))]$? I guess it might be (by some informal reasoning), but this seems to go beyond the scope of what Penrose gave an introduction of. Alternative definitions (for example [here](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~hzhang/c123/Lecture5.pdf), slides 27 and 28) don't seem to be problematic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A=\lambda fgxy.[((fx)(gx))y]$ must be a typo in the book. (It's in my copy too).

The definition that actually works is $A=\lambda fgxy.[(fx)((gx)y)]$.

Usually this would be written as just $\lambda fgxy.fx(gxy)$, but it seems like Penrose doesn't bother to explain the usual rules for omitting parentheses (basically that $MNK$ means $(MN)K$), and instead writes everything fully parenthesized.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, does f(lambda x.gx) have any meaning? Is that the same as fg?

Comment: @LukaMikec: $f(\lambda x.gx)$ and $fx$ "behave the same", in a sense that can be made technically precise. In general $(\lambda x.Mx)$ "behaves the same" as $M$ whenever $x$ does not appear free in $M$ -- this is known as the _eta-conversion_ rule (which Penrose doesn't seem to describe).